# error message with JButton and JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, runtime-error, jfilechooser

I want to have a button with a JFileChooser action. This is the code that I wrote:

```
public class Main {

private static String fullPath;
private JFileChooser inputFile;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    try {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton inputButton = new JButton("Browse input file");

        myPanel.add(inputButton, gbc);

        inputButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
        inputFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        File file1 = inputFile.getSelectedFile();
        String fullpathTemp = (String) file1.getAbsolutePath();
        fullPath = fullpathTemp;
            }
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
            }
        });


} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    }
}
}
```

but the problem is that when I run it, I got a long error message that is part of:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not     supported yet.
at main.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:200)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ActionListener` here is explicitly throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`. Move the `JFileChooser` functionality into the `ActionListener`:

```
input_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
        inputfile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        if (inputfile.showOpenDialog(myFrame) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file1 = inputFile.getSelectedFile();
            String fullpathTemp = (String) file1.getAbsolutePath();
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. With these changes I got this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: Updated. For readers benefit, post your actual code, preferably in Short compilable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) format

Comment: and in this case, what is "myFrame"?

Comment: I used null and got the same error. "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException" :(

Comment: That error is occurring somewhere else. I'd say post another question but with the updated and compilable code

Answer (score 1):

The `ActionListener` interface defines a method called `actionPerformed`. You have two methods in your class, one called `actionPerformed` and another called `ActionPerformed`. The one that gets invoked is the one defined in the interface, namely `actionPerformed`. You have such a method in your class whose only statement is to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. The `ActionPerformed` method, which contains the real code, is never called.

#### Solution:

Strip out the stub `actionPerformed` method and change the name of `ActionPerformed` to `actionPerformed`. Alternatively (though not recommended), make `actionPerformed` invoke `ActionPerformed`.