# JFileChooser and Jbutton errors

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

following this question, [error message with JButton and JFileChooser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553778/error-message-with-jbutton-and-jfilechooser), I want to have a JButton to browse a file using JFileChooser. This is the code we have:

```
package main;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {

private static Component frame;
private static String fullPath;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    Date start_time = new Date();
    try {

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton inputButton = new JButton("Browse input file");

        final JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
        inputFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

        JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

        myPanel.add(inputButton, gbc);

        inputButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
                inputFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
                if (inputFile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file1 = inputFile.getSelectedFile();
                    String fullpathTemp = (String) file1.getAbsolutePath();
                    fullpathTemp = fullPath;
                }
            }
        });
        Date stop_time = new Date();
        double etime = (stop_time.getTime() - start_time.getTime()) / 1000.;
        System.out.println("\nElapsed Time = " + etime + " seconds\n");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
    }
}
}
```

The problem is that after clicking on button "Browse the input file" and choose the file, as soon as I click on OK, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at main.Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:195)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
```

Comment: "I want to have a JButton to browse a file using JFileChooser"  What does that mean?

Comment: Which line is line 195 of your Main.java class?

Comment: This code doesn't compile as-is.  You didn't import `Date` and this line has a typo: `inputfile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Thanks for reminding. Done!

Comment: @tieTYT: It means after clicking on button, file chooser shows up and I can choose a file. I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: String fullpathTemp = (String) file1.getAbsolutePath();

Comment: This stacktrace does not match the code posted. The trace indicates almost 200 lines whereas the posted code has approx 65 lines

Comment: @Reimeus: You are right. The problem is that I copied and then pasted the original code and removed some extra lines (other components of my GUI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've declared `inputFile` 3 times

Once as a static class variable

```
private static JFileChooser inputFile;
```

Then in you're `main` method

```
    final JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
    // this can't possible compile
    inputfile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
```

And then in your `ActionListener`

```
    inputButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser inputFile = new JFileChooser();
            inputFile.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
            if (inputFile.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file1 = inputFile.getSelectedFile();
                String fullpathTemp = (String) file1.getAbsolutePath();
                fullpathTemp = fullPath;
            }
        }
    });
```

It should be possible for any of these to interfere with each other that would produce your `NullPointerException` that I can see, but given the fact that your code example won't actually compile I can only imagine we're not seeing everything

Comment: If I do not declare inputFile in constructor, as soon as I click on button, I will get the error. I edited the code and I think you can compile it.

Comment: Sorry, main method, same problem